# XSRF token validation failed in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation, csrf

I create one form for login which takes userName and password. I also added a csrf field in form. But whenever I intercept the request in burpsuite tool at login. I can see xsrf token in request parameters and I changed it and forwarded the request and off the intercept although xsrf token is changed login is successful. So I think there was not validation of xsrf token.

Here is code:

```
<form id="form-validation" name="form-validation" method="POST" action="/login">

   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <input id="validation-userName"
      name="userName"
      type="text">

   <input id="validation-password"
      name="password"
      type="password">

   <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login" value="login">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

How can I validate xsrf token so if I change the xsrf token then login is failed.

Answer (score 0):

First, depending on the laravel version you use, the new way to include a hidden csrf input in your form blade template is this:

```
@csrf
```

Second, the validation itself happens in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. Have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris). Maybe you excluded some routes from csrf verification.